# How to use jq (or python) to remove a particular key(?) in some JSON?

Tags: python, json, jq, nested-lists

Here is the input json. It is a partial JSON dump of a puppet class extracted from Red Hat Satellite.

```
{
  "Id": 9999,
  "Match": "fqdn=server.fqdn.com",
  "Value": {
    "user1": {
      "order": 90,
      "nofile": {
        "comment": "I want to lose this comment",
        "soft": "65535",
        "hard": "65535"
      },
      "nproc": {
        "comment": "I want to lose this also",
        "soft": "32768",
        "hard": "32768"
      }
      },
    "user2": {
      "order": 90,
      "nofile": {
        "comment": "I want to lose this comment",
        "soft": "65535",
        "hard": "65535"
      },
      "nproc": {
        "comment": "I want to lose this also",
        "soft": "32768",
        "hard": "32768"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to delete all the "comment"s. I can't find an example that does this, or an explanation of something that does this in general. Or I am too stupid to understand what I have read so far.

So my output would be

```
{
  "Id": 9999,
  "Match": "fqdn=server.fqdn.com",
  "Value": {
    "user1": {
      "order": 90,
      "nofile": {
        "soft": "65535",
        "hard": "65535"
      },
      "nproc": {
        "soft": "32768",
        "hard": "32768"
      }
      },
    "user2": {
      "order": 90,
      "nofile": {
        "soft": "65535",
        "hard": "65535"
      },
      "nproc": {
        "soft": "32768",
        "hard": "32768"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any takers?

Comment: What should happen for `{'comment': {'foo': 'bar', 'comment': 'baz'}}`?

Comment: Why both jq and python tag? Also, please show us you own attempt!

Comment: I don't care if it is a jq or a python solution. I have both, and am equally clueless about how both of them work when it comes to nested data. I didn't know how to walk down the JSON tree, so to speak, so I don't have an attempt of my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
del( .. | objects | .comment )
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/6-7sl0JDto) on jqplay

---

In Python, it would look something like this:

```py
def remove_comments(node):
   if isinstance(node, dict):
      if 'comment' in node:
         del node['comment']
      for child in node.values():
         remove_comments(child)
   elif isinstance(node, list):
      for child in node:
         remove_comments(child)
```

Comment: I chose this, because it gives me both a jq and a python answer. These both work for my example data.